# Vite js: how to make sure a custom stylesheet is loaded last, possibly before render?

Tags: vite

I'm using Vite (4.3.9) and Svelte in a project and need to make sure a custom stylesheet is loaded last (mandatory for production, would be nice in development too, if possible).
I've tried using `<svelte:head>` and some javascript to create a `<style />` element but is too slow, the base css are loaded, displayed and then replaced with the custom stylesheet, which isn't a static file but loaded from a url (the url is always the same but the css is loaded from a db and can be different).

I'm looking if is possible with a Vite plugin to process the generated html but I would be fine with any different working solution.